# Regex pattern for email validation

Tags: jquery, regex, email

what sort of a regex pattern should i use to check if an email is in this patter,
xxxxxxx@my.hello.co.uk

xxx being letters and numbers

tried this 
[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[my.hello]+.[ac]+.[uk]

doesn't work though

Comment: There's so many answers here on SO on that topic. Have you done your research?

Comment: used this ^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[my]+(\.ello+)*(\.ac.uk)$... but if its with m.hello.co.uk it still works.. cant get it to work with the exact match for my.hello.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+@my\.hello\.co\.uk
```

The dot '.' is a special char meaning "any char". You must escape it with the slash '\'. I dropped the underscore, the hyphen, and the dot from your 'xxx' part because you want only letters and numbers.

You must aware that

```
0zkr@my.hello.co.uk
```

will be valid (star with a zero digit :) May be you want to read [Jquery validating email using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537866/jquery-validating-email-using-regex.)